# How to render the value of each key within the table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this array that contains multiple objects. How can I retrieve teh value of each key dynamically and render it in the table?

```
data = [
  {
    ADR_CITY_NM: {value: "COCONUT CREEK"},
    ADR_STRT_NM: {value: "123 MAIN STREET"},
    CHK_OUT_TYPE: {value: ""},
    DSTR_NR: {value: "6001"},
    FST_NM: {value: "TEST"},
    LAST_NM: {value: "TESTER"},
    MIDL_NM: {value: "T"},
    PREFIX_NM: {value: "MR"},
    PRI_PHN_AREA_CD: {value: "454"},
    PRI_PHN_NR: {value: "5444444"},
    RGSN_ID: {value: "390000000"},
    SSN: {value: "234344433"},
    ST_CD: {value: "FL"},
    ZIP_CD: {value: "33063"}
  }
  ....
  ....
]
```

I tried using `Object.values()` but that didn't help. Can someone please help?

```
{data.map(item => {
  return (
    <Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell>{Object.values(item)}</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  )
})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add more loop:

```
{data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Table.Row>
            {Object.values(item).map(item2 => (
              <Table.Cell>{item2.value}</Table.Cell>
            ))}
            
          </Table.Row>
        );
      })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `javascript` function code to loop through all your key values in the data then just return the value in your `html`.

```js
data = [
  {
    ADR_CITY_NM: {value: "COCONUT CREEK"},
    ADR_STRT_NM: {value: "123 MAIN STREET"},
    CHK_OUT_TYPE: {value: ""},
    DSTR_NR: {value: "6001"},
    FST_NM: {value: "TEST"},
    LAST_NM: {value: "TESTER"},
    MIDL_NM: {value: "T"},
    PREFIX_NM: {value: "MR"},
    PRI_PHN_AREA_CD: {value: "454"},
    PRI_PHN_NR: {value: "5444444"},
    RGSN_ID: {value: "390000000"},
    SSN: {value: "234344433"},
    ST_CD: {value: "FL"},
    ZIP_CD: {value: "33063"}
  }
]

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```